# Как эффективно отобразить данные из БД на форме WF C#

Tags: c#, winforms, postgresql, datagridview

Концепт: работа со складом

Есть данные в PostgreSQL, форма Windows From, ЯП C#

Отображать в DataGridView - очень долгая прогрузка, при скролле затормаживания.
Как отображать данные так, чтобы при скролле хотя бы не тормозила прокрутка?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Используйте пагинацию

Comment: Уточните, с помощью какой технологии работаете с БД: чистый ADO.NET, микро-ОРМ наподобие Dapper, LINQ-ORM наподобие EF? Тогда можно будет дать конкретные ссылки/советы на реализацию пагинации

Comment: _очень долгая прогрузка_ - может быть дело в sql-запросе? Например, джойнится много таблиц, запрос неээфективный и т. п. То есть нужно померить время выполнения запроса, до привязки к гриду. Если дело в нём - стоит задать отдельный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Используем датагрид с двойной буферизацией. Это ускорит его отрисовку и устранит мерцание.

```
class DoubleBufferedDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    protected override bool DoubleBuffered { get => true; }
}
```

Используем виртуальный режим:
[Walkthrough](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/implementing-virtual-mode-wf-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)
[How to](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-implement-virtual-mode-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)
Благодаря ему данные будут подгружаться постепенно, по мере прокрутки.

Данные из БД загружаем не все сразу, а страницами - используем пагинацию (pagination).